# How to take artifactory package builds details thru api

Tags: api, artifactory

How to take artifactory package builds details thru api. I have only the artifact(package), with this i need to find the builds details which is available under in builds tab...

Please help...

Answer (score 1):

If you mean 'Build Info' then you can use the get Build Info REST API:
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-BuildInfo

Comment: Build info's under build tabs(next to properties) for a specfic package

Comment: The build name and number are saved as properties on the artifact itself. You can take the properties 'build.name' and 'build.number' and use it to extract the build information.
You can get the properties using this rest api:    https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-ItemProperties

Comment: yes. Thanks. Since we are publishing thru npm we dont have build.name under properties tab.. so we need to take those from Builds tab...

Comment: If you don't have them as properties, and as you mention that you publish those via npm client, you will not have the build name and number even on the builds tab as it was not published by a build. Am I'm wrong?

Comment: Yes you are correct. Builds info we are uploading thru API.